# Does disconnecting Android Phone Display Hardware Stop Apps

Tags: android, display

I am running an accelerometer based android app that will run for a few months while phone is on and does nothing else. Some phone allow display not to go to sleep at all which allows my app run fine infinitely. The screen also has only a black display and nothing else apart from background accelerometer listener and occasional http posts. My question is if I remove the display screen while the app is running, would that stop the operating system and/or my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if I remove the display screen while the app is running, would that stop the operating system and/or my app?

In short, it depends on your app architecture (otherwise i.e. music players would require to keep screen on to work). Depending on task you are really doing you may use Alarm Manager to periodically fire your code, or use Service.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Have you tested this? I actually want to physically remove the screen hardware so battery life would be higher.